# Remote MSMQ Receive Error in C#

Tags: c#, msmq

I am trying to send and receive from a remote queue.  I can get the send to work (I see the message in the queue), however, when I try to receive I get an access denied error.  My computer is on a different domain than the remote queue's computer, so I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the issue.  Here is the code snippet:

```
   MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:DEVAPP002\private$\queuetest");
   queue.Send("This is a test");
   Message msg = queue.Receive();  // Kaboom
```

Comment: What is the error that you are/were getting?

Answer (score 2):

To test if permissions are your problem, check that the Anonymous User has read/write access to the queue.

The Everyone user means everyone logged in the domain, at least with respect to the queuing service.

Comment: I agree, it is likely that AnonymousLogon does not have permissions to receive messages. A different domain user would appear as this user which does not fall under the Everyone group.